# What is $E[X|Y]$ if $X,Y$ independent and have the same distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

> Suppose $X,Y$ are two independent integrable random variables with the same distribution.
>
> Calculate
> $E(X|Y)$, $E[X|X+Y]$ and $E[h(X+Y)|X+Y,X-Y]$ where $h$ is a Borel measurable function such that $h(X+Y)$ is integrable.

Since $X,Y$ have the same distribution, then $PX^{-1}=PY^{-1}$ where $P$ is the probability measure.

Then I don't know how to continue with them.

I think once I know how to do $E(X|Y)$ and $E[X|X+Y]$, I can do the third one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y] = \mathbb{E}[X]$$

since they are independent.

By symmetry

$$\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[Y|X+Y]$$

Suppose $X+Y=k$,

$$\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y=k]+\mathbb{E}[Y|X+Y=k]=\mathbb{E}[X+Y|X+Y=k]=k$$
$$\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y=k]=\frac{k}2$$

$$\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y]=\frac{X+Y}{2}$$

Comment: I know $E[h(X+Y)|X+Y]=h(X+Y)$. How to get $E[h(X+Y)|X+Y,X-Y]$?

Comment: to evalute $h(X+Y)$, it suffices to know $X+Y$ right? knowing $X-Y$ doesn't change anything isn't it?